# how to split the file path based on folder

Tags: c#

For example i have file1.txt and below is the content for the file

```
test1\abc\a.xml
test1\abc\n.cs
test1\HB\proc1\candidate1\rel1\spy\can.xml
test1\HB\proc1\candidate1\rel1\spy\globals.xml
test1\HB\proc1\candidate1\rel1\spy\mike.cs
```

Now by reading above file line by line would like to create another file ..say file 2 with the below content

```
test1\abc
test1\abc\a.xml
test1\abc\n.xml
test1\HB
test1\HB\proc1
test1\HB\proc1\candidate1
test1\HB\proc1\candidate1\rel1
test1\HB\proc1\candidate1\rel1\spy
test1\HB\proc1\candidate1\rel1\spy\can.xml
test1\HB\proc1\candidate1\rel1\spy\globals.xml
test1\HB\proc1\candidate1\rel1\spy\mike.cs
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: There is at least an error: *test1\abc\.n.cs* isn't in the second file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [text file: Reading line by line C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21861505/text-file-reading-line-by-line-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

So you can enumerate like this in a fairly straightforward way:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateAllPaths(string[] input)
{
    var hs = new HashSet<string>();

    foreach(var s in input)
    {
        var parts = s.Split(new[]{@"\"},StringSplitOptions.None);

        for(var i = 0;i<parts.Length;i++)
        {
            var section = String.Join(@"\", parts.Take(i+1));
            if(hs.Add(section))
                yield return section;
        }

    }
}
```

To get the individual lines from your original file you can use [`ReadAllLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines(v=vs.110).aspx)

Live example: http://rextester.com/YBOGIH60970

Comment: The `ToList()` is useless. `Split` returns an array. Removing it you have to change `.Count` -> `.Length`. Very good idea of using the `.Take()` :-)

Comment: @xanatos thanks. I forgot to tidy up after a previous iteration.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite complex to do it correctly, I think....

```
var filenames = File.ReadLines("source.txt");
var result = ExpandFilenames(filenames);
File.WriteAllLines("dest.txt", result);
```

and then:

```
static IEnumerable<string> ExpandFilenames(IEnumerable<string> filenames) {
    var alreadyDone = new HashSet<string>();

    foreach (string fileName in filenames) {
        string directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName);

        // "Expand" the parent directories
        var expandedDirectories = ExpandDirectories(directoryName, alreadyDone);

        foreach (string dir in expandedDirectories) {
            yield return dir;
        }

        yield return fileName;
    }
}

// Recursive yield :-) I do know it is slow, but it is easy to write :-)
static IEnumerable<string> ExpandDirectories(string directoryName, HashSet<string> alreadyDone) {
    if (directoryName == string.Empty || alreadyDone.Contains(directoryName)) {
        yield break;
    }

    // We "cheat": we use Path.GetDirectoryName to get the name of 
    // the "parent" directory
    string directoryName2 = Path.GetDirectoryName(directoryName);

    if (directoryName2 != null) {
        var expandedDirectories = ExpandDirectories(directoryName2, alreadyDone);

        foreach (string dir in expandedDirectories) {
            yield return dir;
        }
    }

    alreadyDone.Add(directoryName);
    yield return directoryName;
}
```

Note that I'm going through an `IEnumerable<>` both as a source and as a destination, and I use the `File.ReadLines`/`File.WriteAllLines` overloads that accept `IEnumerable<>`