# How to add commas at the end of each line in a text file after using OpenFileDialog?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Ok so i am making a tool for a special need.
There will be .mif files which i can open as a text file and read the content.

Using something simple like

```
DialogResult openFile = form.openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (openFile == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            int size = -1;
            try
            {
                //Add commas here
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
            }
        }
```

Now how do i add a comma at the end of each line in a file?

e.g something like this

```
319621.99946835 110837.002493295
319640.501385461 110850.59860145
319695.199120806 110879.700271183
```

to something like this (notice the commas at the end of each line)

```
319621.99946835 110837.002493295,
319640.501385461 110850.59860145,
319695.199120806 110879.700271183,
```

Now the pattern is different for this and it occurs 1000s of time in one file

Any ideas?

Comment: Then why first line hasn't comma at the end?

Comment: any attempts on your own to read the file?

Comment: Where is your code to read the file? How are you storing the file lines? Are you writing them back to the file, or just using them in your code?

Comment: im going to write them back into the file which i think i can do

Comment: There are already many answers to your problem, but still an important piece of information is missing in your question to give a reasonable answer. How big are these files that you want to read?

Comment: in terms of file size or file lines? there is about 1000 lines

Comment: File size, if you load all the text in memory, change it and then write it back you have a faster solution but if the file is big you could have memory problems when you start to reformat all those strings in memory

Comment: Size is very small, like 5 kb

Comment: Then, by all means, load everything in memory, transform and write it back

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
string sFilePath = "Insert.File.Path.Here";
File.WriteAllLines(sFilePath, File.ReadAllLines(sFilePath).Select(x => string.Format("{0},",x)));
```

Comment: You could use `File.ReadLines` that returns an `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: File.ReadLines does not read the whole file at one go, so it may crash during runtime if you do it at single line. File.ReadAllLines on the other hand reads the whole file at a time.

Comment: Yes, of course, since you write back to the same file. My mistake.

Answer (score 2):

How to read a file line by line you will find in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21861583/5174469).

at each line do simply:

```
CurrentLine = CurrentLine + ",";
```

Answer (score 1):

If your text file isn't big, you can try this:

```
var path = "myfile.txt";

var lines = File.ReadAllLines (path);

var newContent = string.Join (",\r\n", lines);

File.WriteAllText (path, newContent);
```

It will not add comma to last line.

Answer (score 0):

Use the methods of the `File` class:

```
public static string[] ReadAllLines(
    string path
)

public static void WriteAllLines(
    string path,
    string[] contents
)
```

Like this

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(openFile.FileName);
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++) {
    lines[i] += ",";
}
File.WriteAllLines(openFile.FileName, lines);
```